# Facebook Login With PHP Curl cookies error

Tags: php, curl, facebook-login

I need some help.

I am using curl to login in to facebook. On the first attempt it works fine and saves the cookies as well properly but when I reload the page it displays error that says:

> Sorry, your request could not be processed.Please try again.

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem? Either i have to clear the cookies file again and again or some other solution can fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
// script name: login_to_facebook.php
// coder: Sony AK Knowledge Center - www.sony-ak.com

// your facebook credentials
$username = "";
$password = "";

// access to facebook home page (to get the cookies)
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd() . '/cookies_facebook.cookie');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// do get some parameters for login to facebook
$charsetTest = substr($curlData, strpos($curlData, "name=\"charset_test\""));
$charsetTest = substr($charsetTest, strpos($charsetTest, "value=") + 7);
$charsetTest = substr($charsetTest, 0, strpos($charsetTest, "\""));

$locale = substr($curlData, strpos($curlData, "name=\"locale\""));
$locale = substr($locale, strpos($locale, "value=") + 7);
$locale = substr($locale, 0, strpos($locale, "\""));

$lsd = substr($curlData, strpos($curlData, "name=\"locale\""));
$lsd = substr($lsd, strpos($lsd, "value=") + 7);
$lsd = substr($lsd, 0, strpos($lsd, "\""));

// do login to facebook
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.facebook.com/login.php?    login_attempt=1");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "charset_test=" . $charsetTest . "&locale=" . $locale . "&non_com_login=&email=" . $username . "&pass=" . $password . "&charset_test=" . $charsetTest . "&lsd=" . $lsd);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd() . '/cookies_facebook.cookie');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd() . '/cookies_facebook.cookie');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
// curl_setopt($curl, Curl_, value)
//$curlData is the html of your facebook page
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);

$page_file = "result_output.txt";
file_put_contents($page_file, $curlData . "\r\n\r\n======== RESULT                       ===========\r\n\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook strongly checks your user agent before you can login to prevent scripts as yours. I've already tried to change my user agent with all OS and navigators but I have never been able to login with my script.